# Como puedo saber el ancho de pantalla en donde se esta abriendo la pagina web?

Tags: php, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas iniciales ya en el estado de producción. Todas las páginas del proyecto cargan en el inicio lo siguiente:

```
<style>
  body {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

Lo estuve probando un dispositivo movil y se ve bien, en una PC perfecto. Ahora bien, cuando cargo formularios de ingreso de datos (formulario de registro por ejemplo) hago lo siguiente:

```
<div style="padding-left: 20%; padding-right: 20%">
      ... dentro de este div, todo el formulario de ingreso de datos
</div>
```

En el escritorio, se ve perfecto, da una sensación de prolijidad interesante pero cuando lo veo en el dispositivo movil, se ve demasiado angosto.
Me gustaría detectar el tamaño de la pantalla y en esos casos usar otro div en que no me tenga ni padding-left ni padding-right.
**PREGUNTA 1:** Esto como tendria que hacerlo? 
**PREGUNTA 2:** Podria hacerlo con PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré este código PHP que funciona de maravillas !!!

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['Ancho']) && !isset($_GET['Alto'])){
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">
    <!-- 
    document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?Ancho=\"+screen.width+\"&Alto=\"+screen.height;
    //-->
    </script>";
} else {
    if(isset($_GET['Ancho']) && isset($_GET['Alto'])) {
        // Resolución de pantalla detectada
        echo "Esta es tu resolucion de pantalla: Ancho= ".$_GET['Ancho']." y Alto= ".$_GET['Alto'];
    } else {
        // error en la detección de resolución de pantalla
        echo "No se ha podido detectar la resolución de pantalla";
    }
}
?>
```